# Returning all moved values from thread back to original context in Rust

Tags: multithreading, rust, concurrency

As far as I learned, in Rust to get access to fields from context to the spawned thread I need to move them (not only borrow them) which is ok.
Let's consider example:

```
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let v1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let v2 = vec![4, 5, 6];

    let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("{:?}", v1);
        println!("{:?}", v2);
        (v1, v2)
    });

    let (v1, v2) = handle.join().unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", v1);
    println!("{:?}", v2);
}
```

Here *v1* and *v2* are moved to thread and if I want to use them again in main thread I need to return them from thread and assign them again using handle.join() (which waits until thread is done which is also nice).

**My question:** is it possible to somehow return all moved values back to their original fields? I can imagine that there is much more than just two fields I would move and writing down all of them to return and assign them again would look obscure.

Comment: Not automatically in any way. You could use an `Arc` to pass references to the data instead of passing ownership, but if you need to mutate anything then you'd have to also deal with synchronization.

Comment: You can use [crossbeam::scope](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/latest/crossbeam/fn.scope.html) to borrow data instead of moving it. It's the basis for the [experimental std scoped thread api](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.scope.html)

Comment: crossbeam::scope is what I was looking for, thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to move a lot of variables together, the obvious way to do that is with a struct.

```
use std::thread;

struct ManyFields {
    v1: Vec<i32>,
    v2: Vec<i32>,
    // ...and many others...
}

fn main() {
    let fields = ManyFields {
        v1: vec![1, 2, 3],
        v2: vec![4, 5, 6],
    };

    let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("{:?}", fields.v1);
        println!("{:?}", fields.v2);
        fields
    });

    let fields = handle.join().unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", fields.v1);
    println!("{:?}", fields.v2);
    // and many others...
}
```

Depending on exactly why you needed the thread to take ownership, you may be able to avoid that altogether using [scoped threads](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/latest/crossbeam/thread/struct.Scope.html). Scopes introduce an explicit lifetime in which a thread is guaranteed to finish, allowing you borrow values as long as they outlive the scope.

```
use crossbeam::scope;

fn main() {
    let v1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let v2 = vec![4, 5, 6];

    scope(|scope| {
        scope.spawn(|_| {
            println!("{:?}", v1);
            println!("{:?}", v2);
        });
    })
    .unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", v1);
    println!("{:?}", v2);
}
```

---

From rust 1.63 you will be able to do this without a third party crate, as it will be part of std.

Comment: also creating struct is nice suggestion, I thought about it, but I can think of situation where grouping some fields would not follow logic, but I didn't realise that it doesn't move fields that are not used inside so it's probably not a big problem anyway

Comment: Don't make promises about scoped threads coming in 1.63, they may not (soundness issues with NLL stabilization that may block them).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create a helper function to return them automatically. You can even use a macro to avoid the re-assignment:

```rust
macro_rules! spawn_with_data {
    {
        | $( $captured:ident ),* $(,)? | $code:expr
    } => {
        let ( $( $captured, )* ) = ::std::thread::spawn(move || {
            $code;
            ( $( $captured, )* )
        }).join().unwrap();
    };
}

fn main() {
    let v1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let v2 = vec![4, 5, 6];

    spawn_with_data!(|v1, v2| {
        println!("{:?}", v1);
        println!("{:?}", v2);
    });

    println!("{:?}", v1);
    println!("{:?}", v2);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d5d07c191d2deec779f3d249406e3343).

But I agree using scoped threads is better here.

Comment: This actually looks pretty nice as well, I kinda expected some syntax where I can explicite say which values I move as arguments and therefore expect to return them afterwards. Thank you ^^